# Wagtail: Extend page model

Tags: extend, wagtail

I have created in the past multiple pages for Wagtail.

Example:

```
class PlainPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(BasicStreamBlock, null=True, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

Now I would like  to an extend all this pages by giving them the possibility to set them to no-index.

For this reason I would like to add a boolean field to the promote_panel.

What would be the best way adding this feature to all pages I have already created?

```
no_index    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
    FieldPanel('no_index'),
]
```

What would be the correct Wagtail way, to extend all my Page classes with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Django's [Class Mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), it is possible to add fields to all existing models without too much hassle.

### 1. Create a Mixin

First - create a new `CustomPageMixin` (name this whatever you want) that extends the `Page` model and has the meta `abstract=True` set.

```py
class CustomPageMixin(Page):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

    no_index = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # adding to content_panels on other pages will need to use THIS promote_panels
    # e.g. promote_panels = CustomPageMixin.promote_panels + [...]
    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
        FieldPanel('no_index'),
    ]
```

### 2. Update ALL existing page models

Update all your models in use to use the mixin, instead of extending the `Page` class, they will actually extend your mixin directly.

```py
from ... import CustomPageMixin

class StandardPage(CustomPageMixin):
    #...

class HomePage(CustomPageMixin):
    #...
```

### 3. Run Migrations

Note: This will add the `no_index` field to ALL pages that now extend your new mixin.

- `./manage.py makemigrations`
- `./manage.py migrate`

### Potential Issues with this approach

- This may not be the best way to do this, as it is a bit indirect and hard to understand at first glance.
- This does not actually change the Page model fields, so it will only be available when you access the actual specific models' instance via [`Page.specific`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.specific)
- It will be a bit more tricky to use this for special `Page` types such as `AbstractEmailForm`.

Comment: What will happen to my data if I extend my classes with "CustomPageMixin" instead of the normal "Page" model? Is this for Django a complete new DB Table or does Django understand to keep the DB Table and extend it only with one more field?

Comment: Best to test this in a safe way, make a backup etc, when I did this locally (with the Wagtail Bakery Demo) it essentially just added the field `no_index` to all the models.